# Need help building script to: Get-Content, Search List of Employees for their Manager, Search Manager, Get Managers Email

Tags: powershell

friends.

Here's what I'm trying to do here, but not skilled enough to build the script.

Using Powershell, I wish to :

(1) Import a csv file containing multiple lines.  Each line (row) contains an employee's name, employee's email address, employee's manager's name.

The csv file column headings for these are "EmployeeName", "EmployeeEmail", and "ManagersName" respectively.

(2) Script will, for each employee in the list, grab their manager's name, then enter manager's name into a string.

(3) Using the manager's name (now in a string), search that same csv file (in its entirety) for the manager's name in the employee name column (the manager is also an employee, duh).

(4) Once the manager's name is found in the employee name column, grab that manager's email address and dump results into a new csv file using column headings "EmployeeName","EmployeeEmail","ManagersName","ManagersEmail".

(4) Repeat for all employees in the csv file.

Thanks in advance. I know this may be a tall order.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and where you got stuck

Comment: Greetings.  Venkatakrishnan posted his script that works perfectly.  Thanks, Sigy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the input is in below format

[image]

The script for your requirement goes like below one

```
$Inputs=import-csv "InputFile"


foreach($Coll in $Inputs)
{
$EmployeeName= $Coll.EmployeeName
$EmployeeEmail=$Coll.EmployeeEmail
$ManagerName=$Coll.ManagersName
$ManagerEmail=$Inputs | where {$_.employeename -eq $ManagerName} | Select-Object EmployeeEmail -ExpandProperty EmployeeEmail

"$EmployeeName,$EmployeeEmail,$ManagerName,$ManagerEmail" | Out-File "OutFilePAth" -Append

}
```

The output looks like below one
[image]

Hope this HElps.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect!  Works like a champ. :-)